# Sublime Text 2: how to force all files to open in a single window?

Tags: macos, sublime-text-2

I like using a single Sublime Text 2 window with multiple tabs.  Currently, when I click on files in Finder that are openable via ST2, they open in separate ST2 windows.  How do I force ST2 to open tabs in a single ST2 window for new files?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Since you're on OS X, this is a feature that is enabled by default. You will need to go to the Default Settings (under Preferences) and scroll down to the "open_files_in_new_window" setting, which is on line 280. Change the `true` value to `false`. Do not delete the comma, though.

(In Sublime Text 2.0.2, this is line 301, and Preferences is under Sublime Text 2 main menu heading.)

See the comments for a brief discussion of the advantages of changing "Settings – User" instead of "Settings – Default".

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should always copy the settings you want to change in the User settings and change its value there. If you update Sublime Text, the default settings might get overwritten.

Comment: are these prefs for Sublime or for Finder ?

Comment: They are for Sublime Text

Comment: It did not work for me.  I changed the setting, closed the existing instance of the app, opened file1 with Sublime, that started a new instance (with hopefully the new setting taken effect), went to open file2 ...  same thing again, new instance of Sublime

Comment: On Windows this settings not work. On my Win7 files opened from Explorer (for example) goes to new window. I can't fix it.

Comment: @amphibient: If you're opening files via the command line, see [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/537912/119772).

Comment: It's also possible @amphibient had `user settings` which were overriding these `default settings`.

Comment: I am trying same, but I am able see that file and property, but it is not editable. what should I do.

Comment: How to do this on Sublime 4 on Mac? There is already property "open_files_in_new_window": "never", but also a disclaimer "On Mac, this value is overridden in the platform specific settings". Where to find those platform specific settings?

Answer (score 19):

I opened Sublime Text2-->Preferences-->Settings User and changed it to have the below contents

```
// Settings in here override those in "Default/Preferences.sublime-settings", and
// are overridden in turn by file type specific settings.
{
    // OS X only: When files are opened from finder, or by dragging onto the
    // dock icon, this controls if a new window is created or not.
    "open_files_in_new_window": false
}
```

Answer (score -2):

My sublime text 2 opened new file into a new tab by default, and later on for some reason, tabs disappear (prolly b/c I opened a folder in sublime text). New file now then only can be opened into a new window.

To undo that, simply click "View" on the menu then "Show Tabs". Any new file will be opened into a new tab!