# Open Sublime Text 2 with new tab instead of new window

Tags: macos, bash, sublime-text-2

I've got an alias to open files in Sublime Text 2:

```
alias sub='/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime\ Text\ 2'
```

But this spins up another instance of Sublime Text 2 (complete with restoring all the open files and folders in my other instance).

I would like to get files to open up as a tab in the current instance, which must be possible, since this is what *right-click > Open with... > Sublime Text 2* does.

Any idea how to do that from the command line?

Comment: That's not how it is for me. When I call `subl file1` and then `subl file2`, it opens a new tab for `file2` next to `file1`. Quite the contrary, when I call `open -a 'Sublime Text 2' file2`, I get a new Sublime window.

Comment: Can you confirm that your alias matches mine?  Are you using & to keep the cmd prompt from holding on to the instance?  Also, what are you settings for the following options in SublimeText2>Preferences>Settings-Default?



 // OS X only: When files are opened from finder, or by dragging onto the
    // dock icon, this controls if a new window is created or not.
    "open_files_in_new_window": true,

    // OS X only: This controls if an empty window is created at startup or not.
    "create_window_at_startup": true,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that you have the wrong alias. Here's the correct one for Sublime Text 3:

```
alias subl='/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'
```

This is an alias that Sublime Text specifically provides for macOS. It will not block execution and—by default—open files in a tab next to the ones that are already open.

---

If you want to know more about why your alias didn't work, read on.

Application packages in OS X have an `.app` suffix, but when launched, they actually launch a binary that's specified in `Info.plist` in said package. This is the binary your alias links to, in the `MacOS` folder.

Running an application from the GUI or through Launch Services (e.g. via `osascript` or `open`) makes OS X open that binary, but at the same time ensure it's only launching one instance of that app. When you call the binary directly, you bypass this restriction and launch another instance of the application—unless the application has measures for preventing two instances from being launched, which normally OS X handles.

Also, as a side effect, launching the binary will block the terminal execution until you exit the program or suspend it to the background. Using the built-in `subl` from Sublime Text returns control to your terminal, as it actually uses a Launch Services call to open the Sublime package instead of addressing the binary in `MacOS` only.

Since you're basically launching a second Sublime Text instance, it'll show you the files it previously had opened, because that's its default behavior.

Comment: I'm opening multiple files using Python. How can I use this code to  keep them in one window?

Comment: @DaniSpringer Just run `sub *.py`.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Here's what I'm working with: https://github.com/DaniSpringer/readmes-opener/blob/master/file.py (it seems to open them _usually_ in the same window if Sublime is already open/has an open window - still not sure). Where would `sub *.py` go in there? Or that's for a different approach?

Comment: @DaniSpringer Oh, I see.  Well, from Python you could try to locate the `subl` executable that is part of the Sublime Text app bundle (on macOS at least) and then pass your file names as arguments, e.g. `subprocess.run(["/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl", "file1.txt", "file2.txt"])`. But in general I think you're overengineering your program. If you use Bash you could simply run `shopt -s globstar` (for recursive globs), and then `subl ~/code/**/pizza*.txt`.

Comment: @DaniSpringer Also, check Sublime's preferences. There's a `open_files_in_new_window` setting that controls startup behavior.