# Open files in new Sublime window on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sublime-text-2, window

I currently switched from gedit to Sublime Text. One thing I liked with gedit, but what is missing in Sublime, is that new files are opened in a new window *when the current window is in another workspace*.

Sublime Text creates a new tab in the current window. I would rather have a new window in the workspace where I open the file. I know the `"open_files_in_new_window": true,` option, but that's only for *OS X*, while I'm on *Ubuntu 14.04*. (Consequently, the solutions provided in [Sublime Text 2: how to force all files to open in a single window?](https://superuser.com/questions/402116/sublime-text-2-how-to-force-all-files-to-open-in-a-single-window) won't work.)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but as a temporary work-around you can simply drag the tab outside the window to create a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS here + Sublime 3 + FileZilla.

I have looked everywhere for an answer on how to make this work on Ubuntu but to no avail.

Actually, as you might know by now, setting "open_files_in_new_window" to FALSE works ONLY in OSX. So I remebered that FZ has some stuff on editors.

Long story short, all you need to do is, in FZ, go to: 
Edit > Preferences

then: File editing > Always use default editor (assuming you have set Sublime as such).

That is all you have to do! Hope it helps someone.